# Trying to find out average of marks...but getting wrong ans

Tags: c

Friends in following code i am trying to get some of the average in float...i tried manually my ans should be in fraction, but here it comes in rounded fig...please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//finding out the average marks for students ....

float average (float []);

int main()
{
    int i;
    float total_avg=0;

    float arr_1[] = {10.2, 22.9, 36.04, 89.1, 94.1, 10.8,};

    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
             printf("%2f\n",arr_1[i]);
             printf("\n\n");


     total_avg = average (arr_1);   
     printf("Total average : %3f\n",total_avg);     


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    }

float average (float a[5])
{
      int sum = 0, i;
      float total;

      for(i=0; i<6; i++)
      {
           sum = sum+a[i];
           }
     total = sum/5;

      return total;

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've fixed the type of `sum` as pointed out by bash.d, your answer will still be wrong.  `arr_1` contains 6 elements but you divide by 5 when calculating the average.  You need to change the calculation of `total` to

```
total = sum/6;
```

Or, better still, change `average` to

```
float average(float* a, int num_elems)
{
    float sum = 0
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<num_elems; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum/num_elems;
}
```

and call `average` like

```
total_avg = average (arr_1, sizeof(arr_1)/sizeof(arr_1[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use int as sum? Use `float` instead:

```
float average (float a[5])
{

  int sum = 0,
  float total, sum = 0.0f;

  for(i=0; i<6; i++)
  {
       sum = sum+a[i];
       }
 total = sum/5;

  return total;

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ...i think i need to do my basics proper...thanks!